# Not understanding the output of this forEach() method

Tags: javascript

Consider this example:

```
var a = {
    "Check" : function doThis(value, index, ar) { 
        if(value >= 10) {
            document.write(value + ", ");
        }
        else {
            document.write("The array element is less than 10, ");
        }
    }       
}

var arr = [12, 20, 2, 3, 15];
document.write(arr.forEach(a.Check));
```

Which results in:

```
12, 20, The array element is less than 10, 
The array element is less than 10, 15, undefined
```

I don't understand why there is an extra element in the array which is undefined. Does it have something to do with defining the callback function in an object?

Comment: `arr.forEach()` doesn't have a return value, i.e. it "returns" `undefined`, which you're also writing. (Note the lack of a trailing comma behind it.) There is no extra element in the array, your code is buggy.

Comment: Ahhh that makes sense - thank you! I was using `document.write` just for testing purposes.

Comment: You should use `console.log` instead for testing, it is vastly superior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

replace:

```
document.write(arr.forEach(a.Check));
```

with:

```
arr.forEach(a.Check);
```

With `document.write(arr.forEach(a.Check));` you are printing what the `arr.forEach()` call returns (`undefined`)